# Why does Ubuntu add a .5" margin to the top when printing to my HP PSC-750?

Tags: printing, hp

It's that time of year again when I'm trying to print off all my tax forms.  When I print to my printer, an HP PSC-750, from Ubuntu, I consistently get a 1/2" margin at the top of the document.  According to [this page](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&dlc=en&docname=bpu04822&lang=en&lc=en&product=57769#N736) however, the top margin required by the printer is only .07".

In previous releases of Ubuntu (such as the 10.04 prerelease I was running this time last year), it appears that something in the print pipeline would automatically scale the output to fit these margins.  This year, 12.04 Beta is trying to use the whole page (unless I manually tell it to scale and manually tell it to use a 1/2" margin), resulting in part of the text being cut off.

Does anyone know why, when using the default print driver provided by Ubuntu, the printer would behave this way?  I see the same behavior whether I have the printer connected directly to my laptop, or if I use my Debian stable server as a print server.  Is this a problem with the printer itself?  The strange 1/2" top margin has always been a problem since it was first purchased, but I've only ever used it with Linux, never with Windows, so I can't say whether this is a Linux-specific problem.

Comment: Same problem here.
Unable to get margins less then 20mm
I hate this!
Maybe it is this bug? #994630?

Answer (score 12):

I'm having the same problem.  My printouts are cut.

System is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with HP Photosmart 6510 printer.

Here what I found (talking about A4 and cm, however, should be the same with Letter and inches, I just cannot try it with my setup)

1. Printer (at least mine) has a "scale-to-fit" options which allows pdf to be rendered properly.  The printout is scaled down, so it is smaller, but the margins are looking good.

   Printers ->  -> Job Options -> scale-to-fit

   This is of course not acceptable for predefined paper positions or if I want data to be as large as possible (for me Music Sheets and Labels for CDs)

   so there is
2. the option to use the full paper size

   During print:

   Page Setup -> Paper Size -> ... Borderless ...

   This allows to print pages without borders.

Hope this helps to solve you problem as well ;-)

Klaus

Comment: (2.) Works like a charm !

Comment: Number 2 just worked for me with my HP Envy 5540 which was trimming 15 cm from the top of my images despite what the print preview showed. 

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like it's not printing with the correct page size. Please check the default setting in System Settings / Printing / [your printer] / Properties / Printer Options.

If you are sure the page size is correct, please file a bug on launchpad and attach the CUPS error log right after you printed something with wrong margins [1].  Feel free to assign me so that I find it quicker ;) (larsu)

[1] https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems#CUPS_error_log

Answer (score 3):

**Solved** by deleting printer in System->Administration->Printers and reinstalling it with another driver.

Ubuntu is 12.04 LTS (Precise).

Printer is HP Officejet G55.

Actual (good) driver is "HP OfficeJet G55 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.8-pre1".

Previous (bad) driver was "HP Officejet g55, hpcups 3.12.2".

*Noted* that Ubuntu "Printer test page" border adjust to hardware margins.

Answer (score 1):

Historically, many printers have not been able to print to the edges of the paper.  It quickly became standard practice to leave a 1/2" margin all the way around.  In some cases it is even enforced by printer drivers.  It looks better, is convenient for holding papers in your hands, for binding them on the left or top, and for writing notes in the margins so today most programs default to having 1/2" margins.

If your printer driver will permit it, most programs that can print will also allow you to adjust the margins.  You may even be able to set the default margins in whatever program(s) you use.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue - HP Officejet 6500 Wireless and 12.04 LTS - by changing the driver.
First go the the printer window and remove the printer.
Then add a new printer and choose the proper driver (the one including `hpcups` was the wrong one and the one including `hpijs` was ok).

Margins are now back to normal.

Comment: Can you please add the steps to achieve what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

Again a problem with Printer Margins caused by MusicSheets on PDF using Ubuntu 12.04 (same on 13.10).

Problem: Header is not printed correctly, header text is simply cut in the first lines.

What I did (Evince GNOME Document Viewer 3.4.0 on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS):

Print with following options set during printing:

.. to allow maximum output

> Page setup -> Paper size = A4 Borderless 210x297mm

... to show headers properly

> Page Handling -> Page Scaling = Fit to Printable Area
>
> Page Handling -> Select page size using document page size = tick option to select

... and everything is fine and pretty!

Answer (score 0):

Since latest versions (in mind 13.10, 14.04) have fall down this option you may take the command line way, to list printer options use `lptoptions -p <printer name>` to define options use `lpoptions -p <printer name> -o option=value`

For this precise issue, you should use `lpoptions -p <printer name> -o fitplot`

And after this command you will get the option `fitplot=true` listed.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

**I can confirm SUCCESS**.
Problem: Printing a PDF on XUbuntu 14.04 cut of the margins at the top and bottom.
**Solution in my case:** Updated the HPlip package.

1. Downlaod the package from http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/hplip/hplip-3.14.10.run
2. Open terminal and change directory to download folder.
3. Make Executable by entering `chmod +x hplip-3.14.10.run`
4. run `bash hplip-3.14.10.run`
5. in my case I chose to override existing older version but it would be smart to delete it first
6. Restarted PC
7. Open HPlip utility
8. Added new printer and chose to install it with the CUPS WebInterface
9. Printed PDF successfully with all the margins correctly printed!

Comment: WARNING! I just ran that exact installer and it wiped my ENTIRE home directory. Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I tried printing from Qpdfview for the first time instead of Evince and was able to adjust the top and other margins in the Properties. The other printing options are similar to evince. As the person who asked the question, I too print a great number of tax forms and for the first time it printed it as it should be.

Another advantage is to be able to shrink the window far smaller than Evince.